# Is there a decent Perl editor that I can run on Windows laptop that will read/write to my linux server?

Tags: editor

Not a fan of the editors on Linux.  Was hoping there might be a decent editor that works on my Windows laptop that would read and write directly to my server?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In case anyone comes upon my question, I found the editor Sublime to fit my needs.  Plus, here's the link I found that enables it to use SFTP.  It might be considered pricey by some people's standards as you have to buy TWO licenses.

[Someone else's YouTube vid on making Sublime work over SFTP as it doesn't straight out of the box](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LZMkcepNxF0)